# How to change report direction at run-time

Tags: oracle, oraclereports

In Oracle Report 6i;
How can I change the direction of report `Left to Right` , `Right to Left` at report run-time ?..

Any one has an idea ?.. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any *setting* you might set (using the `SRW` built-in package), so - as far as I can tell, there's no simple "on/off" switch you might use.

However, what you might try to do is:

- create two layouts: one left-to-right and another one right-to-left
- each of them should be enclosed into its own frame
- create a parameter which will let you decide which direction to use
- create a Format Trigger; it would make a switch between those two layouts. For example:

  ```
  -- left-to-right frame
  return (:par_left_to_right = 'LTR');

  -- right-to-left frame:
  return (:par_left_to_right = 'RTL');
  ```

  So, if you pass LTR, left-to-right will be displayed (while right-to-left won't).